# Never "Keep current list of tags tables also"

Tags: ctags

If I'm working in a directory with its own `TAGS` file, and then I move to another directory, with its own `TAGS` file, I always get asked this question:

```
Keep current list of tags tables also? (y or n)
```

I never want to bring the list of tags tables with me between directories, so I'd like to default the answer to this question to `n`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

aha!

```
(setq tags-add-tables nil)
```

seems to do the trick