# tags-add-tables / list of tag tables

Tags: spacemacs, ctags

I can't find a concise answer to this question, only big manuals for which I'm not sure reading them will give me the answer...
Spacemacs & haskell-mode are now giving me tag navigation by default (appeared with a MELPA upgrade, it's a feature I didn't have before).
I'm using it now, however each time I change folder with tag navigation, emacs is asking:

> Keep current list of tags tables also? (y or n)

I've seen [that other question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14802/never-keep-current-list-of-tags-tables-also) and so I see that the `tags-add-tables` setting is the way to go, however I honestly have no idea whether I want to answer yes or no... Is there a builtin emacs manual I can look at with brief information on the topic of tag tables, that would explain which is the compromise here?

Honestly I would expect `spacemacs`, or maybe `haskell-mode` to make that decision for me :-(

Answer (score 2):

From emacs describe-variable (SPC h d v):

```
tags-add-tables is a variable defined in ‘etags.el’.
Its value is nil
Original value was ask-user

Documentation:
Control whether to add a new tags table to the current list.
t means do; nil means don’t (always start a new list).
Any other value means ask the user whether to add a new tags table
to the current list (as opposed to starting a new list).

You can customize this variable.
```

So whether you want to answer yes or no depends on if you want to keep the previous directory's symbols in your symbol table or not.